# Binomial identity: Clever idea for a short proof?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

When answering *[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873306/sum-identity-using-stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind/1877760#1877760)* I had to cope with this binomial identity:

> The following holds true
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}\sum_{j=0}^i\binom{i}{j}(-1)^{k-i}j^{i-j}
> =\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}\sum_{j=0}^i\binom{i}{j}(-1)^{i-j}j^{k-i}\qquad\qquad k\geq 0
> \end{align*}

Although LHS and RHS look very similar, I have troubles to find a short transformation from one side to the other. At the time the proof looks like

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^k&\binom{k}{i}\sum_{j=0}^i\binom{i}{j}(-1)^{k-i}j^{i-j}\qquad&\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{k-i}\sum_{j=0}^{k-i}\binom{k-i}{j}(-1)^{i}j^{k-i-j}\qquad& i\longrightarrow k-i \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{k-i}\sum_{j=i}^{k}\binom{k-i}{j-i}(-1)^{i}(j-i)^{k-j}\qquad& j\in[0,k-i]\longrightarrow j\in[i,k] \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom{k}{k-i}\binom{k-i}{j-i}(-1)^{i}(j-i)^{k-j}\qquad&\text{exchange sums}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^{i}\binom{k}{k-j}\binom{k-j}{i-j}(-1)^{j}(i-j)^{k-i}\qquad&i\longleftrightarrow j\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^{i}\binom{k}{k-i+j}\binom{k-i+j}{j}(-1)^{i-j}j^{k-i}\qquad&j\longrightarrow i-j\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^{i}\binom{k}{i}\binom{i}{j}(-1)^{i-j}j^{k-i}\qquad&\\
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

Since this derivation looks somewhat cumbersome i am wondering if there is a more efficient index transformation possible or another *shorter* way to prove this identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be a set with $k$ elements. Both sides can be interpreted as counting, with signs, choices of

- a subset $I$ of $K$,
- a subset $J$ of $I$, and
- either a function $K \setminus I \to J$ (on the LHS) or a function $I \setminus J \to J$ (on the RHS).

Picking $I$ and $J$ is equivalent to picking a partition of $K$ into three disjoint subsets, namely $K \setminus I, I \setminus J$, and $J$. The LHS and the RHS are related by switching $K \setminus I$ and $I \setminus J$, which is what your index transformations are accomplishing.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But at the time I do not consider it as precise combinatorial interpretation of the identity I've stated above. Since the index region is overlapping, e.g. when $i=j$ I wouldn't call it a partitioning. Another aspect is the function $j^{i-j}$ at the LHS and $j^{k-i}$ at the RHS is not simply related e.g. via cyclic permutation of indices. So, I do not see from your combinatorial interpretation that both sums will give the same value.

Comment: @Markus: $i = j$ isn't a problem; that just means $I \setminus J$ is empty. $j^{i-j}$ counts functions $I \setminus J \to J$, and $j^{k-i}$ counts functions $K \setminus I \to J$; they get sent to each other upon switching the two. Things might be clearer if the sets were renamed $K_0 = K \setminus I, K_1 = I \setminus J, K_2 = J$. Then the LHS counts the sum, over all such tuples of sets, of $(-1)^{|K_0|} |K_2|^{|K_1|}$, while the RHS counts the sum, over all such tuples of sets, of $(-1)^{|K_1|} |K_2|^{|K_0|}$. These are switched if you switch $K_0$ and $K_1$. Is this clearer?

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thanks a lot, It's clear to me now. (+1)